# Vanilla linux : Sign root file system

Tags: linux

I'm booting an x86 vanilla (4.9.20, 64bits) with grub.
The root file system is located on an ext3 formatted disk.
It works fine.

Is it possible to sign the root file system so that if it's changed by attacker it will not boot ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: And any log entry will invalidate the signature...

Comment: you can do something like this with a TPM (trusted platform module), you encrypt your root drive and store the key in the TPM chip, then you sign your bootloader, and the TPM only allows the bootloader to decrypt the rest of your system if it can verify the signature.

Comment: Rob - Thank you very much. Does it mean that I have to modify grub ?

Comment: You probably want to look into immutable Linux distros.

Comment: Alex - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that a general purpose OS distro did not change is more difficult than it might seem. Quite a few files are modified during normal operations.

If the entire file system were unchanged, preventing writes would not be a problem. Try booting your distro with the root file system read only, either a mount option or make the block device read only. After you know how to boot a rescue disk or emergency initrd, because this is not likely to work. There's quite a few files modified during normal operations: logs, locks, user data.

An image based software update system has to deal with how to handle writes. Usually by separate mount points for volatile data, possibly using overlay. However by itself that doesn't help with the problem of maintaining integrity. And you might not be ready for software update by copying file system images.

Further, there's a deeper challenge of trusting the bootloader. How do you know your kernel has not been tampered with? Or that you aren't booting the expected root file system? Would be nice if this could be cryptographically anchored in a root of trust.

RHEL security hardening guide proposes [Keylime to verify boot integrity](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/assembly_ensuring-system-integrity-with-keylime_security-hardening#con_how-keylime-works_assembly_ensuring-system-integrity-with-keylime). This would be a tool rooted in a TPM that [attests to system integrity as early as possible](https://keylime.readthedocs.io/en/v7.9.0/design/threat_model.html), using UEFI boot combined with Linux integrity subsystem.

Benefit would be detection of many low level changes of the system state, from the bootloader to the kernel to software, even when facing advanced threats. And to finally get to your goal of isolating failed nodes, [secure payloads](https://keylime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/secure_payload.html) can make the decryption of certain files contingent on attestation. Or run revocation scripts. Unknown boot signature, remove TLS and SSH certificates, and it cannot communicate. Of course logging of such an event is very interesting and could trigger a security response.

Downside, such a project would be complex and high maintenance. Determining known good boot state based on arcane UEFI registers. Excluding files for integrity subsystem checking. Key management for TPMs. Needing a TPM in the first place, affecting which hardware, hypervisors, and clouds you use. Integration of secure payloads and revocation scripts. Deploying and maintaining server components. Keeping this working through changes of hardware and software and boot configuration.

Not the same thing, but there is a different approach to allow list software that can execute. Maybe not trust rooted in secure hardware, but preventing execution of arbitrary programs stops a lot of threats. Again look to the software distro for implementation examples, [RHEL is promoting fapolicyd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening).